# make different instances out of the same class?

Tags: c++

header of CMain

```
CSomeClass a
```

using CSomeClass inside CMain.cpp

```
a.SomeFunction();
a.m_bVar = SomeVar;
```

the question is, how do i get a different, second instance of CSomeClass that uses the same varables inside CSomeClass but with their own individual values **without** the use of new?

i know `pSomePointer = new CSomeClass[2];`will make a different instance, but is it possible without using new?

Comment: why do you want to not use `new`? You could `malloc` space for it directly and initialize it manually but that's basically what `new` does anyway.

Comment: @twain249 Why do you want to? It makes no sense here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph that's what I'm saying. He asked for a way to create an instance WITHOUT new and I gave him one and said it's pointless.

Comment: @twain249 using `malloc()` in c++ is *usually* pointless and dangerous. Also, avoiding using `new` makes perfect sense - it is much easier to maintain the code. Most C++ users usually prefer using `vector` and automatically allocated variables when possible.

Comment: @twain249 You misunderstood me. My question was: why would you want to use `new` here? It’s as useless as `malloc` here.

Answer (score 2):

```
CSomeClass b;
```

Just declare a new variable.

Furthermore, `a` probably shouldn’t be defined inside a header but also inside `CMain.cpp`, just where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is,

```
CSomeClass myObjects[2];
```

will create two [automatically allocated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) objects.